# Mysql querys in PHP PDO returning in different array structures

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have a couple of simple MySQL procedures:

A:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectUsername`(_id INT(11))
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Select username given id'
BEGIN
    SELECT username FROM registered WHERE id=_id;
END
```

B:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectCountryIdOfUser`(_id INT(11))
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Select country id given registered user id'
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNTRY_id FROM registered WHERE id=_id;
END
```

Now, for some reason, after putting it through a PHP PDO statement:

```
$stmt=$dbconnect->prepare("CALL selectUsername(:userid);");
$stmt->bindValue(':userid',$userid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The following results are seen using `print_r($result)`:

A:

```
Array ( [username] => 'Test' )
```

B:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [COUNTRY_id] => 235 ) )
```

What I was wondering, is Why does B return the result in a nested array? So now, when I want to refer to the value, I have to use the 0 array: `$result[0]['COUNTRY_id']`

Comment: In my experience, `fetchAll()` always returns an array of hash arrays as in your B: case. Are you sure you didn't simply use `fetch()` in the A: case?

Comment: Nah I definitely used fetchAll in both cases ... My only guess could be that because 'A' is searching using a Primary Key (id), it is only expecting one row ... Whereas 'B' is searching for a Foreign Key (COUNTRY_id) ... Don't know if it works that way ...

Comment: It does not work that way. The `fetchAll()` method does not change what it returns based on the way the query is optimized in the MySQL server. Read the section on "Return Values" here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php